# airpods flashing orange and sound is gone in left

Tags: airpods

I have had my airpods for about a couple months and they have worked completely fine. I charge my airpods every 2nd night, today after charging them they have been flashing orange and the sound is gone in the left. I know that orange means it needs to be charged but i am charging them right now and they are still flashing orange. When i remove one pod from the case, the light changes to green but when I put them both in together it flashes orange. Also they won't connect to anything device it doesn't know and won't reset using the button. pls help

Answer (score 2):

Press the reset button on the white case(you can miss this as it is flush with the case) hold the button until the light goes white. Then pair it with Bluetooth again... hey presto